# How to get available sizes from configurable product using SOAP?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, configurable-product, soap

We created configurable products based on size attribute. say A is configurable product having children of different sizes like S, M, XL.

How to get available size like S,M,XL from parent product using SOAP in Magento CE 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case,you need to create extension.

**Step1:** Create module file at `app/etc/modules/Stackexchange_Magento61215.xml`

```
Code:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento61215>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>            
            <depends>
                <Mage_Api />
            </depends>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento61215>
  </modules>
</config>
```

### Step2:Create Module api files:

**StepA:** Create config.xml file at

```
app\code\local\Stackexchange\Magento61215\etc
```

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Stackexchange_Magento61215>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Stackexchange_Magento61215>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <magento61215>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento61215_Helper</class>
      </magento61215>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <magento61215>
        <class>Stackexchange_Magento61215_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>magento61215_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </magento61215>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

**StepB:** xml code for api,file is  `api.xml app\code\local\Stackexchange\Magento61215\etc\`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <magento61215_api translate="title" module="magento61215">
                <title>Myapi</title>
                <acl>magento61215/api</acl>
                <model>magento61215/api</model>
                <methods>                    
        <getoptionbyparent translate="title" module="magento61215">
            <title>Fetchconfig</title>
        </getoptionbyparent>
                </methods>
            </magento61215_api>
        </resources>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <magento61215 translate="title" module="magento61215">
                    <title>Magento61215</title>
                    <sort_order>2000</sort_order>                    
                    <getoptionbyparent translate="title" module="magento61215">
                        <title>Fetchconfig</title>
                    </getoptionbyparent>
                </magento61215>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

**StepC:** Define Model file from where you  get Data:

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento61215_Model_Api extends Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract
{        
public function getoptionbyParent($parentProId = null)
{

    $Product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($parentProId);
    $result=array();                
    $apiHelper = Mage::helper('api');
    if($Product->getId()){
               $allProducts = $Product->getTypeInstance(true)
                    ->getUsedProducts(null, $Product);

    try {
        foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
            $result[]=$product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
        }
        $data=array_unique($result);
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('filters_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    }
    }
    return $result;
}


}
```

`StepD:` create Helper file  `Data.php at app\code\local\Stackexchange\Magento61215\Helper`

```
<?php
class Stackexchange_Magento61215_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

Now you  can get data by

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://yourhost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$session = $client->login('******', '******');
$date = $client->call($session, 'magento61215_api.getoptionbyParent');

XML-RPC 
$client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://yourhost/api/xmlrpc/');
$session = $client->call('login', array('******', '******'));
$date=$client->call('call', array($session, 'magento61215_api.getoptionbyParent'));
```